# Is asking to translate a short paragraph from English to Spanish on topic here?

Tags: discusión, ámbito, traducción

I want to see if I'm allowed to ask such a question in the main site?

> Would you please translate the following paragraphs into Spanish?
>
> - a proposal for creating a remote sensing and photogrammeetry Q&A site    in StackExchange Network is in commitment phase now
> - All the instructions you need to know to be an effective committer to    the remote sensing and photogrammetry proposal in StackExchange
> - You can also have a look at the homepage and the "definition phase is    over!" page of this google site.
> - There I've summarized all the efforts from last year and also have    linked  to valuable tutorials which introduce the StackExchange
>     network and make you more familiar with what I'm trying to do
> - Let's make a website for remote sensing and photogrammetry real. Let's all press "commit" button!
> - Please share or like the post as much as possible. This will help it    be seen on more news feeds and it will likely be seen by more
>     interested people.
> - Please share the page and invite others to like it in order to have more committers and probably a successful launch
>
> I need them to post about [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/90327/remote-sensing-and-photogrammetry?referrer=8G2asYAyI_To9RoVf1VtPg2) in facebook pages that
>   are related to the topic and promote it. Because as you know and as
>   facebook suggests, posts in local languages receive more likes and
>   more attention and so they might be seen by more people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, as is now it would be off-topic. You would be asking to translate some text without showing any attempt.

For the several reasons we have for closing as off-topic, your question would fall in two of them:

> - Questions asking for translations are off-topic unless prior research effort is clearly indicated; we're here to help you learn, not provide a bulk translation service.
> - Questions asking for corrections in a text e.g. "are there any mistakes in this text?" are off-topic. You can ask specific sentences in separate questions that may help other users. For more information, see what you can ask [here](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

So, what should you do to make the question on topic?

Show your attempts and research! Tell us what you think that could be a translation for the text and indicate what your specific questions are.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. In fact I don't know a word of Spanish and am not learning right now. I had the same question in [french se](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/a/620/11584) and [german se](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/a/1192/23750) and they advised me to ask in the chat room. Am I allowed to do so in the spanish chat room, too?...As you see I just want the translation of 7 short paragraphs and am not turning the chat room to a bulk translator. Also I'm not searching for a professional translation. Something more exact than google translate is enough (human translation

Comment: You are welcome :) Currently, we do not have a chat to gather, but I think it is a nice idea, so I just reopened one: [La Tertulia](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1792/la-tertulia). Feel free to enter, we'll try to take a look at it.

Comment: not machine one), just without major grammatical error (for example disposition of verbs, subjects, etc and understandable for anyone who knows spanish). As I said they're just for posting on facebook. I would have hired a translator as they suggested in [Japanese se](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1649/18067) but the level of accuracy and a short passage won't persuade any professional translator do the job!

Comment: thanks, I did see your comment after posting the previous one. thanks a lot :)